# How do you change the ownership of an iPod

Tags: ipod

I am trying to add music to an iPod using Rhythmbox but although I can see and play what is on the iPod I cannot change it because it belongs to root.  I have tried running nautilus as sudo and it refuses to allow me to change any of ownership's.

Answer (score 1):

To change to ownership of a mounted device (your iPod), you must remount it with new ownership. Here's how:

On the command line, type

```
mount
```

to list all your mounts. Find your iPod's line. Read `man mount` to understand this line. I don't have an iPod, but it might look like:

```
/dev/sdc on /media/w3/0123-4567 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
 ^device    ^mountpoint              ^filesystemType   ^options
```

Now, "remount" the device with

```
# YMMV - device, mountpoint, filesystem, options MUST
# come from YOUR system - these example values will not work for you!
device="/dev/sdc"
mountpoint="/media/w3/0123-4567"
filesystem="vfat"
# remove "uhelper=udisks2"
options="rw,nosuid,nodev,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush"
# new options
uid=$(id -u)
gid=$(id -g)
options="remount,uid=$uid,gid=$gid,$options"
sudo mount $device -t $filesystem -o $options $mountpoint
```

Now, you will own the device, and can change it to y9our heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

Although the remonting answer is correct, there might be an easier way.  Plug the iPod into a [Windows machine with iTunes and do a Factory Restore](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252) within iTunes.  After a Factory Restore, if you want a rooted device then re-root the device under your own name.